# Espresso test: TestNavHostController.setCurrentDestination not being set correctly

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-architecture-navigation

In my Espresso test I have set up to create an Activity with a Fragment and Navigation Graph:

```
protected inline fun <reified A : AppCompatActivity, reified F : Fragment> launchFragment(
    @NavigationRes navigationResource: Int,
    @IdRes fragmentId: Int
) {
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<A, F> {
        navController.setGraph(navigationResource)
        navController.setCurrentDestination(fragmentId) //<-- I believe the problem is here
        this.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever {
            //navController.setCurrentDestination(fragmentId)
            Navigation.setViewNavController(this.requireView(), navController)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified A : AppCompatActivity, reified F : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            A::class.java
        )
    )

    ActivityScenario.launch<A>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        fragmentFactory?.let {
            activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
        }
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(F::class.java.classLoader),
            F::class.java.name
        )

        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "") //<-- I have also tried the Id of the fragment container in the activity
            .commitNow()

        fragment.action()
    }
}
```

And my Activity and Fragment load up fine, but if I log the result of `findNavController().currentDestination` it shows me the first screen in my flow (I am trying to test from the 4th screen)

This is not such a big problem except that when in my test setup the Fragment tries to open a new fragment I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination packageName:id/action_screen4_to_ErrorScreen cannot be found from the current destination Destination(packageName:id/screen1Fragment) label=screen1 class=screen1Fragment
```

So the `Navigation` thinks I'm on the `startDestination` fragment and not the fragment that I'm trying to load, so I can't navigate away FROM my Fragment in test. I am not trying to pop, I know there would be no backstack.

The following code is what I use to navigate inside my fragment, which works fine "in flow".

```
findNavController()
    .navigate(
        R.id.action_screen4_to_ErrorScreen,
        null
    )
```

I have tried

- accessing the `requireView()` instead
- using `binding.root.findNavController()`
- `requireActivity().findNavController(requireView().id)`
- `Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragmentContainerId)`
- `Navigation.findNavController(requireView())`

I have created a repo that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/qbalsdon/espressoTestFramework

Comment: In what method are you logging `findNavController().currentDestination`?

Comment: In both `onCreateView` and the method that responds to the `SingleLiveEvent` that triggers the Navigation

Comment: Well your `observeForever` won't have fired by the time `onCreateView` is called - that's only called **after** `onCreateView` as per [its documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwnerLiveData()). Do you see the same thing in `onViewCreated()` when using `binding.root.findNavController()`? That's what you've set when you do `Navigation.setViewNavController`

Comment: Yeah it's the same for `onViewCreated()`. But now it threw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().` - even though onCreateView does return a view

Comment: I'm confused, which is it? It can't both be 'the same' and also throw an exception somewhere. Can you share your code?

Comment: I have made a repo for the problem: https://github.com/qbalsdon/espressoTestFramework

Comment: You're not using `binding.root.findNavController()`, you're using `findNavController()`, which doesn't look at the `Navigation.setViewNavController` value first (it looks at the fragment hierarchy). Note that because you're using `MainActivity`, you're building **two** instances of your Fragment - one in your real `NavHostFragment` and one in your test. That's probably not actually what you want at all (which is why trying to run your test in `MainActivity` is not an API built for you).

Comment: I have listed all the attempts, not just findNavBarController. I saw the tutorial I followed used a dummy activity - I’ll create a PR on my code but I’m pretty sure it yields the same result because I tried that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that this is quite possible, and you can load a fragment into any activty if you use deep linking rather than trying to set the destination after the activity is loaded:

```
protected inline fun <reified A : AppCompatActivity> launchFragment(
    @NavigationRes navigationResource: Int,
    @IdRes fragmentId: Int,
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null
) {
    launchFragmentWithDeepLink<A>(fragmentArgs, null, navigationResource, fragmentId)
}

inline fun <reified A : AppCompatActivity> launchFragmentWithDeepLink(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
    @NavigationRes navigationResource: Int,
    @IdRes fragmentId: Int
) {

    val launchIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
        .setGraph(navigationResource)
        .setComponentName(A::class.java)
        .setDestination(fragmentId)
        .setArguments(fragmentArgs)
        .createTaskStackBuilder().intents[0]

    ActivityScenario.launch<A>(launchIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        fragmentFactory?.let {
            activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
        }
    }
}
```

And then the usage:

```
@get:Rule(order = 1)
override val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
@get:Rule(order = 2)
val activityTestRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

private fun showFragment() {
    launchFragment<MainActivity>(
        R.navigation.navigation_graph,
        R.id.my_fragment_id
    )
}
```